# How can I get the value of a TextEditingController that is contained in a class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app with lots of textfields that creates a pdf with the textfield data, recently I made the change of changing String vars to TextEditingControllers to have more control over my Textfields. But they all return null values to the pdf and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.. So I may ask how to properly initialize a class that is in another archive and how to get its values

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Simple: TextEditingController _tedController = TextEditingController();
   to get the value: _tedController.text;

Use the dot access operator then say text. you can also perform multiple functions with .value

Comment: This worked as an isolated variable so thank you very much! I need to call the texteditingcontroller from a class that is another archive, because I don't want to add more than 50 vars to my form archive, so I would pretty much appreciate if you could tell me how to correctly call my texteditingcontrollers. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: I'll be glad to help but I can't still get what you really want. Please elaborate further. Did you want to create a single variable for the controller but use it multiple times from another class?

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better, I have a form with more than 50 textformfields and for cleaness sake I used to get my string vars that saved the textfield data from a class that is in another archive, so I just had to initialize the class in the form like:  `final ACModel _acModel = new ACModel();` and use the vars like `_acModel.ubication`. I recently had to change my string vars to a TexteditingController and that way of referencing my vars no longer worked, so I'm looking a way to work with the TextFormfields. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Add a snippet of the your code in your question

Comment: I already found what was wrong, your contribution was important tho. I will try to answer my question if I have time, Thanks for your attention!